# Chain Rule applied to a scalar (result of a product between 2 vectors)

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vectors

I have a doubt, I am not able to come up with a solution.

I have 3 vectors:
$\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times1}$

I want to compute the derivative:

$H=\frac{\partial \vec{a}^T \vec{b}}{\partial \vec{c}}$ which should be $\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times3}$ because $\vec{a}^T \vec{b}\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times1}$

If I apply the chain rule to $H$ I get:

$H=(\frac{\partial\vec{a}}{\partial\vec{c}})^T\vec{b}+\vec{a}^T(\frac{\partial\vec{b}}{\partial\vec{c}})$

An hypothesis of my problem is that $(\frac{\partial\vec{b}}{\partial\vec{c}})=0$, so $H=(\frac{\partial\vec{a}}{\partial\vec{c}})^T\vec{b}$ which is $\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times1}$.

How can I get something which is $\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times3}$?
The first thing that came to my mind is just to put a transpose in the chain rule formula like that:

$H=[(\frac{\partial\vec{a}}{\partial\vec{c}})^T\vec{b}]^T+\vec{a}^T(\frac{\partial\vec{b}}{\partial\vec{c}})$

But I am not able to justify this operation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know if I can answer but here is some extra literature which might help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: 1. This is a product rule, not a chain rule. 2. Your formula for H makes no sense, because it says to add a column vector to a row vector. So the error is in the application of the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\eqalign{
A &= \frac{\partial a}{\partial c}, &\, B &= \frac{\partial b}{\partial c} \cr
}$$
Then
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\,(a^Tb)}{\partial c} &= A^Tb + B^Ta \cr
}$$